# EditText Example Android code

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I'm new developer Android.
Where I can find an Example of EditText ??
In XML please.
I tried this but doesn't work for me.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"   
 android:orientation="vertical">
 <EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/bus"
    android:hint="@string/hello_world"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Bye Bye

Comment: android:layout_height="2dp" change to android:layout_height="wrap_content" In future pls read some tutorials before asking, vogella or developer.android are good sources

Comment: what you get after running the code?

Comment: here is a simple example for login form, go through this and then start working,  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_login_screen.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here I've found a [little tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/edittext/android-edittext-example/) for you.
Work it through and it will be a bit clearer for you.

Good luck!